# Qt/QML Android best practice to send a custom Intent (share URL)

Tags: android, qt, android-intent, share, qml

I was wondering if there are any best practice tips for sending custom android intents from QML (or c++ for that matter).

should I create a custom android activity and use the QAndroidJniObject class to call it or are there any better ways?

My intention is to create a simple share URL function from QML to other android apps.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend QtActivity with additional static method:

```java
package org.whatever

public class YourActivity extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static YourActivity instance;

    YourActivity() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static void shareUrl(QString url) {
        //create intent here
        //can use instance object
    }
}
```

On c++ side call shareUrl method using QAndroidJniObject

```cpp
class QmlInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        QmlInterface();
        Q_INVOKABLE void shareUrl( QString url );
};
```

and implementation:

```cpp
void QmlInterface:: shareUrl( QString url )
{
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod( "org/whatever/YourActivity",
                                         "shareUrl",
                                         "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                         QAndroidJniObject::fromString( url ));
#endif
}
```

Using static method on java side simplifies jni call significantly because you don't have to get Activity instance. Because Activity context is needed to send Intent static **instance** member object is used on java side.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I have one question though: does the activity has to extend QtActivity for any specific reason or can a default Activity also be used since it just calls the static method via JNI?