# How to call Intent in QML?

Tags: android, qt, qml

I developed an android app, and want to use a Intent method to call the app using QML at the initial process and by clicking button. How can I do that? Thanks.

The androidmanifest.xml is demonstrated as below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.digital.multiviewplayer" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MultiviewPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of or .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="DisplayShift" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should use Android extras, try [QAndroidIntent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidintent.html). [This](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/30/intents-with-qt-for-android-part-1/) article could be useful too.

Comment: Typical approach [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672522/qt-qml-android-best-practice-to-send-a-custom-intent-share-url)

Comment: Any examples used in QML is preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt/QML Android best practice to send a custom Intent (share URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672522/qt-qml-android-best-practice-to-send-a-custom-intent-share-url)

Comment: If you feel your question is different from the one in the linked one, please clarify. In the answer it is clearly described how to send an intent from a Qt/QML object. All you need to do is to expose a `Q_INVOKABLE` or `slot` from C++ to QML, and call it there.